# Curve fitting for exponential functions

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

The equation is as follows:

```
y=|A-B*exp(-x/C)|
```

Where`||` denotes absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `curve fitting` toolbox in which you can define your own custom fitting function.

Another option is to install the `ezyfit toolbox` available [here](http://www.fast.u-psud.fr/ezyfit/).

Comment: I tried curve fitting toolbox, and used my own custom fitting function, but I don't know how to write the expression exp(-x/c), which leads to error in Matlab. And I also don't know how to express the absolute value.

Comment: Your equation has to be written in this way 

`abs(a-b*exp(-x/c))` 

where `abs()` is the absolute value. 

Which kind of error do you get? 

In the `curve fitting` toolbox have you defined the `dataset` you want to fit?

As an extra note: are you sure about your fitting equation? 

It looks a bit strange, maybe the absolute value is missplaced and the correct equation is `a-b*exp(-abs(x)/c)` that is symmetric around zero.

Comment: >> x=[25 50 100 180 300 500 750 1100 1500];
>> y=[3088 2284 908 592 2124 3293 3807 3963 3976]; Here is the data. But the fitting curve seems wrong. I did follow your instruction. What 's wrong with it?

Comment: you cannot use fit the function `a-b*exp(-abs(x)/c)` because the x data are not referred to zero!
I got a decent fit taking into account the horizontal  translation along the x axis introducing an extra parameter `x0`. 
So the modified function is 

`a-b*exp(-abs(x-x0)/c)`.

With the data you provided I got these parameters (in parethesis their confidence interval):


`a =        3905  (3265, 4545);
b =        3931  (2432, 5431);
c =       140.1  (25.82, 254.3);
x0 =       162.5  (127.5, 197.6)`

The fit is not wonderful, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the [cftool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/cftool.html) command